# How to create index on computed fields in peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I have the following peewee model (simplified):

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    a = IntegerField() # actually a ForeignKey
    b = IntegerField(null=True) # ForeignKey
    c = IntegerField(null=True) # ForeignKey
    d = TextField()
    e = TextField(null=True)
```

I want to create a unique index on fields (a, b, c, d) treating NULL values as equal. For example it should be possible to insert (1, NULL, NULL, 2, NULL) only once.

I managed to write raw SQL query to add the index (-1 should be safe, since b and c are foreign keys on int>0)

```
CapsuleTranslatorBundle.add_index(SQL('''CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_idx ON foo (
    a, # a_id if a is a foreign key
    COALESCE(b, -1),
    COALESCE(c, -1),
    d
);
'''))
```

I tried

```
idx = Foo.index(Foo.a,
                fn.COALESCE(Foo.b, -1),
                fn.COALESCE(Foo.c, -1),
                Foo.d, unique=True)
Foo.add_index(idx)
```

but got

```
peewee.OperationalError: near "USING": syntax error
```

How can I add the index without using raw SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just finished analyzing the code myself. It happened to be a bug, already confirmed and fixed by @coleifer in the repository - thanks!

Here's a quick fix that produces a valid SQL (for sqlite3) on peewee 3.7.0 (may come in handy until the fixed code is released):

```
idx = Foo.index(Foo.a,
                Value(fn.COALESCE(Foo.b, SQL('-1'))),
                Value(fn.COALESCE(Foo.c, SQL('-1'))),
                Foo.d, unique=True)
Foo.add_index(idx)
```

produces

```
('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "foo_a_d" ON "foo" ("a", COALESCE("b", -1), COALESCE("c", -1), "d")', [])
```

---

Without `SQL('-1')` (using just `-1`) I get another error `peewee.OperationalError: parameters prohibited in index expressions` and the generated query is: `'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "foo_a_d" ON "foo" ("a", COALESCE("b", ?), COALESCE("c", ?), "d")', [-1, -1]`

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug where the function object is being interpreted incorrectly due to some code deep in the ModelIndex construction.

Fixed here:

- https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/a4621ba0e9516eba0f6e056579218c9c0731b195
- https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/1c1a4f92d59426bc7a38d8ad8cbf709548626c13

Comment: First I thought - strange, I had tested on the latest code from GIT. Then I noticed: "coleifer committed an hour ago" ;) Thank you for fixing this issue.

Comment: No worries, glad you had a question on it, only sorry you ran into this issue.